# test class method that return another class

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I want to test whether the `main class` method of `getService` return the correct `new class` based on the correct conditional

```js
// main.js
import ServiceA from './serviceA'
import ServiceB from './serviceB'

class Main {
   constructor(){}
   getService(serviceName){
     switch(serviceName){
       case 'serviceA':
          return new ServiceA()
       case 'serviceB':
          return new ServiceB()
       default
          return null
     }
  }
}
```

Would it be possible to test that the returned class is correct? I tried something like this

```js
import Main from './Main'

describe('Main method', () => {
  describe('getService given ServiceA', () => {
    it.skip('should return an instantiate of ServiceA class', function () {
      const main = new Main();
      const getService = spy(main, 'getService');

      main.getService('serviceA');

      expect(getService).to.be.an.instanceOf(ServiceA);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a need to `spy` on `getService()`. Since you are just testing the input and output of the `getService()` without any dependencies. Spying would allow to see call count and arguments passed to the spy to see if it was called inside the method you are testing. How you had it is mostly correct as it is.

import Main from './Main'

```
describe('Main method', () => {
  describe('getService given ServiceA', () => {
    it('should return an instantiate of ServiceA class', function () {
      const main = new Main();
      const result = main.getService('serviceA');
      expect(result).to.be.an.instanceOf(ServiceA);
    });
});
```